# When the sum of independent Markov chains is a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, markov-chains

I try to find as much as possible cases, when the chain $Z(t) = |X_1(t)-X_2(t)|$ is Markov, where $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ are independent, discrete-time and space, preferably non-homogeneous Markov chains.
I started to search for the sum of independent Markov chains and I found this statement in Stoyanov J. - Counterexamples in Probability (2ed., Wiley, 1997)(p.229, one can google it and find in google books):

> ... the sum of two Markov processes need not be a Markov process. Note, however, that that the sum of two independent Markov processes preserves this property.

That seems very strange to me and I wish to find the proof or at least the statement elsewhere.

---

EDIT: The way of thinking how it may look like for a sum of two independent Markov chains (If I want to prove that the sum of two independent Markov chains is again a Markov chain):

Let $Y(n) = X_1(n)+X_2(n)$. Then

$P(Y(n+1) = i_{n+1} \ | \ Y(n) = i_n, ..., Y(0)=i_0) =$

$= P(X_1(n+1)+X_2(n+1)=i_{n+1}\ | \ X_1(n)+X_2(n)=i_n,...,X_1(0)+X_2(0)=i_0)=$

$=/ (?) / = \sum_{j+k=i_{n+1}}P(X_1(n+1)=j,X_2(n+1)=k \ | \ \cdot)=$

$=/\text{X's are independent}/ = \sum_{j+k=i_{n+1}}P(X_1(n+1)=j \ | \ \cdot)\cdot P(X_2(n+1)=k \ | \ \cdot) = $

$= /\text{Markov property + (??) } / =  \sum_{j+k=i_{n+1}}P(X_1(n+1)=j \ | \ X_1(n)+X_2(n)=i_n)\cdot P(X_2(n+1)=k \ | \ X_1(n)+X_2(n)=i_n)=$

$=P(X_1(n+1)+X_2(n+1)=i_{n+1} \ | \ X_1(n)+X_2(n)=i_n) = P(Y(n+1)=i_{n+1}\ | \ Y(n)=i_n)$.

Here I am uncertain about (?) and (??) steps.

Comment: Do you want to know whether the sum of two independent Markov chains is a Markov chain or whether the sum of two independent Markov processes is a Markov process? The title of your question suggests the former, but the question itself the latter.

Comment: @saz As far as I understand, Markov chain is a sort of discrete-valued Markov process, so if this statement is true about general Markov processes, it should work for Markov chains too.

Comment: @saz I'm interested in the sum of two independent chains.

Comment: A more general framework for the question is whether some function of a Markov chain is still a Markov chain, that is, if $X=(X_n)$ is Markov and $Y_n=G(X_n)$, when is $Y=(Y_n)$ a Markov chain? Your case is when $X=(X^1,X^2)$, which is Markov if $X^1$ and $X^2$ are independent and Markov. This general property is called [lumpability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpability), sufficient conditions for lumpability are well known, one meets it naturally when studying hidden Markov models (of great relevance in applications), and gg'ing `lumpability markov` provides relevant references.

Comment: @Did Thank you, we have already met [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373442/when-the-sum-of-markov-chains-is-a-markov-chain-dumb-algorithm) where I have actually used the lumpability (formula (3)) and was checking the condition using a program. Looks like my explanation there was overcomplicated, because I didn't know that lumpability is a rather well-known thing, so I received no answers except yours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the sum of two independent Markov chains is not a Markov chain.

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(X=0) = \mathbb{P}(X=1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and set $X_n := X$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Obviously, $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov chain. Moreover, let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$, $Y_0 := 0$, be a Markov chain independent from $X$ with state space $\{-1,0,1\}$ and transition matrix

$$P := \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\ 0 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now set $Z_n := X_n+Y_n$. Then, by the independence of $X$ and $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$, we have

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(Z_2 = 0 \mid Z_1 = 1, Z_0 = 1) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(Z_2 = 0, Z_1 = 1,  Z_0 = 1)}{\mathbb{P}(Z_1 =1, Z_0=1)} \\ &=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_2 = -1, Y_1 = 0,  X= 1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1 =0, X=1)} \\ &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_2 = -1, Y_1 = 1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 0)} \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X=1)} \\ &= \mathbb{P}(Y_2 = -1 \mid Y_1 = 0) = \frac{1}{4}. \end{align*}$$

On the other hand, a very similar calculation shows that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(Z_2 = 0 \mid Z_1 = 1) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_2 = -1, Y_1=0) \mathbb{P}(X=1) + \mathbb{P}(Y_2 = 0, Y_1=1) \mathbb{P}(X=0)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 0) \mathbb{P}(X=1) + \mathbb{P}(Y_1=1) \mathbb{P}(X=0)} \\ &= \frac{5}{12} \neq \frac{1}{4}. \end{align*}$$

This means that $(Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is not a Markov chain.

Comment: Thank you! However, this brings be to the very beginnig of my search. It is very strange that I can find almost nothing on this question (cases when the sum will be a Markov chain).

Comment: @hcl14 Yeah. Since independence is already a rather strong condition, I guess that there is simply no reasonable condition for the sum being again a Markov chain.

Comment: You might be interested in the algorithm and a program I posted here: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373442/when-the-sum-of-markov-chains-is-a-markov-chain-dumb-algorithm)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but it's the top result on google when one searches for "[sum of Markov chains](https://www.google.com/search?q=sum+of+markov+chains&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)" -- at least it is for me at the time of writing.
I just wanted to suggest a *much* easier and more intuitive solution.

Let $U$ and $V$ be independent Bernoulli$(\tfrac12)$.
Let $X_n = U$ for all $n$.
Let $Y_n = -(-1)^n V$ for all $n$
Let
$$Z_n = U - (-1)^n V.$$
In particular, $U-V = Z_0 = Z_2 = Z_4 = \cdots$ and also $U+V = Z_1 = Z_3 = Z_5 = \cdots$.

Suppose that the 'present' is time $n = 2$, and we wish to consider the distribution of $Z_3$. Note that $Z_2 = 0$ implies $U = V$, and so $Z_1 = Z_3 = 2U$. Knowing $Z_1$ now determines precisely $Z_3$. For example,
$$ P(Z_3 = 2 \mid Z_2 = 0, Z_1 = 2 ) = 1 \neq P(Z_3 = 2 \mid Z_2 = 0, Z_1 = 0). $$
(In particular, if one sees consecutive $0$s, then one knows that $U = V = 0$.)

Comment: Thank you! I remember also writing [some algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373442/when-the-sum-of-markov-chains-is-a-markov-chain-dumb-algorithm) on that problem which might be interesting for you, but it's a long time since university so I can't tell how correct is it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. By the way, I had forgotten that you wanted independent Markov chains initially. The solution posted yesterday was for dependent ones. I've changed it -- only very minorly -- just a moment ago to be independent :)