# Sequence of random variables with Gaussian noise - does it satisfy Markov property?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have the following sequence of random variables,$\{\mathbf{X}_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, defined recursively by

$$
\mathbf{X}_{n+1} = \mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{X}_{n} + \mathbf{\Psi}_{z}\mathbf{Z}_{n} + \mathbf{\Psi}_{w}\mathbf{W},
$$

where $\{\mathbf{Z}_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a (bivariate) Markov chain and $\{\mathbf{W}_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is (bivariate) i.i.d. (and normally distributed) noise, thus also a Markov chain. Furthermore, $\mathbf{\Phi}$, $\mathbf{\Psi}_{z}$ and $\mathbf{\Psi}_{w}$ are constant (matrices). Since each $\mathbf{X}_{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ only depends on the previous state, i.e. $\mathbf{X}_{n-1}$, this makes it a Markov chain? We do not have to regard $\mathbf{Z}_{n}$ and $\mathbf{W}_{n}$ since these are already Markov, am I correct in my assessment?

I found on this [page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/is-ar1-a-markov-process) about AutoRegressive processes that the AR(1) process is a Markov chain given that the noise is mutually independent, which seems to apply to my case, although I have the process $\{\mathbf{Z}_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ involved also.

Edit: possible solution I came up with (inspired by [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/is-ar1-a-markov-process)) is that $X_{n}$ only depends, as seen by the recursion, of $X_{n-1}$. Thus, the probability distribution of $X_{n}$ conditional on its history reduces to simply the conditional of the prior state $X_{n-1}$.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365430/when-the-sum-of-independent-markov-chains-is-a-markov-chain

Comment: @E-A Thank you, that helped. So now I know that we cannot simply call any sum of Markov chains a Markov chain, how can I go about proving/disproving that this particular is a Markov chain? Is finding a counter example the only way to show that it is *not* a Markov chain? Finding one such seems to take a lot of creativity.

Comment: Eh, it is not the "only" way, but it is probably the best way for this problem. (Another method of disproving things is showing that if this were true, you would be breaking some other fundamental fact of the universe) As for it being hard to construct a counterexample, you can be inspired by the link I gave there; the intuition is that if I give you two values of X_n, you can say something reliable about where Z_n is in its own Markov chain. I would actually argue that most examples you generate for Z_n will result in X_n not being a Markov chain.