# Prove or disprove that the sum of Markov processes is Markov

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Markov Processes, is their sum a Markov process?
> $\require{color}$

Intuition tells me that in general this should not hold. I want to verify this mathematically.

I am aware of specific counterexamples of the above question; however, I am interested in knowing wether the below approach is viable:

For simplicity consider the setting of $(X_k)_{k=0}^n$ and $(Y_k)_{k=0}^n$ being discrete-time Markov Chain (I believe the argument is easily extended to other cases as well), and define $Z_k := X_k+Y_k$, $k\geq 0$. Then

$$\begin{aligned}
P(Z_{n}=z_{n}\vert Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1},\dots,Z_{0}=z_{0})&=P(X_{n}+Y_{n}=z_{n}\vert X_{n-1}+Y_{n-1}=z_{n-1},\dots,X_{0}+Y_{0}=z_{0})\\
&=\sum_{y_0,\dots,y_n}P(X_{n}+Y_{n}=z_{n}\vert X_{n-1}+Y_{n-1}=z_{n-1},\dots,X_{0}+Y_{0}=z_{0},{\color{red}{Y_n=y_n,\dots,Y_0=y_0}})P(Y_n=y_n,\dots,Y_0=y_0)\\
&=\sum_{y_0,\dots,y_n}P(X_{n}=\underbrace{z_{n}-y_{n}}_{\text{not a R.V.}}\vert X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}-y_{n-1},\dots,X_{0}=z_{0}-y_0)P(Y_n=y_n,\dots,Y_0=y_0)\\
&{\color{blue}{=}}\sum_{y_0,\dots,y_n}P(X_{n}=z_{n}-y_{n}\vert X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}-y_{n-1})P(Y_n=y_n,\dots,Y_0=y_0)\\
&=\sum_{y_0,\dots,y_n}P(X_{n}=z_{n}-y_{n}\vert X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}-y_{n-1})P(Y_n=y_n\vert Y_{n-1}=y_{n-1})P(Y_{n-1}=y_{n-1},\dots,Y_0=y_0).
\end{aligned}$$
would this be going in the right direction? From this last line you cannot conclude much without any further assumption on the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, which would make the implication in the question false for general $X$ and $Y$.

In $({\color{blue}{=}})$ I used the Markov Property of $X$ and in the last equality that of $Y$.

---

Edit:

Can the last sum be reduced/written in the form
$$P(Z_{n}=z_{n}\vert Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1}){\color{red}\cdot(\text{some other terms})}$$
so that it would be clear that the Markov Property would not hold in general with the given assumptions?

Comment: What are you trying to prove? Are you looking for a neat counter-example? Are you trying to understand why the sum fails to preserve Markovianity?

Comment: Here is a post on MSE with a counterexample : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365430/when-the-sum-of-independent-markov-chains-is-a-markov-chain

Comment: @AugustoSantos Yes precisely, I am trying to understand as to why the sum fails. More specifically, my initial objective was to get to a form as the following:
$\require{color}$
$$P(Z_{n}=z_{n}\vert Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1},\dots,Z_{0}=z_{0})=P(Z_{n}=z_{n}\vert Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1}){\color{red}{\cdot(\text{some other term})}},$$ 

which would directly show that indeed the Markov Property does not hold in general, given the limited information in the question (extra terms that appear on the right hand side of equality).

Comment: @TheBridge The counterexample by saz is very neat; however, I am more interested in showing that the Markov Property does not hold without providing a specific example, but by algebraically showing that $P(Z_{n}=z_{n}\vert Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1},\dots,Z_{0}=z_{0})$ cannot be reduced to $P(Z_{n}=z_{n}\vert Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1})$ without further assumptions, and therefore disprove the initial statement. I hope this is clear.

Comment: On the other hand you can have the sum of two markov processes still be markov, take the sum of 2 independent Brownian motions for example as if you halve the sum you still have a Brownian motion so it's a markov

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are not looking for a specific counter-example, but perhaps for a fundamental reason on why it fails, here are my few cents on the problem.

**Intuition.** If you know the value of the *macroscopic* variable $X(t)+Y(t)$ at the present time $t$, you cannot tell how it will evolve next without zooming into the *microscopic* state $\left(X(t),Y(t)\right)$. This is fundamentally what breaks the Markovianity down. Imagine that you have a collection of $N$ distinct binary Markov processes (or chains) $X_i(t)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,N$. In this slightly simpler framework, your question could be cast as: is the fraction of processes at state $1$ a Markov process? I.e., is the macroscopic state-variable $Z(t)\overset{\Delta}= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i(t)$ Markov? No, because if you know that $30\%$ of the processes are at state '1', you cannot tell what is the rate of transitioning to, e.g., $0.3+1/N$ without having to look at the identity of the processes at state '1', i.e., without looking at the microscopic state-variable $\left(X_1(t),X_2(t),\ldots,X_N(t)\right)$. Unless, of course, in some degenerated framework where the $X_i's$ have the same dynamics (or distribution) and they are all independent.

**Mathematically.** Let $f(x,y,z)\overset{\Delta}=\mathbb{P}\left(X(t)+Y(t)=z\left|X(t)=x,Y(t)=y\right.\right)$. In the framework where the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ are distinct, then $f(x,y,z)\neq f(y,x,z)$, i.e., $f$ is not symmetric in the first two variables (or exchangeable in the higher-dimensional framework counterpart). On one hand, we have

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X(t+1)+Y(t+1)=n\left|X(t)+Y(t)=m\right.\right)=\sum_{w\in \mathcal{E}}\mathbb{P}\left(X(t+1)+Y(t+1)=n\left|X(t)=m-w,Y(t)=w\right.\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y(t)=w\right)=\sum_{w\in \mathcal{E}} f(m-w,w,n)\mathbb{P}\left(Y(t)=w\right)$$,

and on the other hand, we have

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X(t+1)+Y(t+1)=n\left|X(t)+Y(t)=m\right.\right)=\sum_{w\in \mathcal{E}}\mathbb{P}\left(X(t+1)+Y(t+1)=n\left|X(t)=w,Y(t)=m-w\right.\right)\mathbb{P}\left(X(t)=w\right)=\sum_{w\in \mathcal{E}} f(w,m-w,n)\mathbb{P}\left(X(t)=w\right)$$.

Only by accident (or in some degenerated frameworks) these two coincide and from here you can build a family of counter-examples.

In summary, $X+Y$ is not Markov because the function $g(n,m)=\mathbb{P}\left(X(t+1)+Y(t+1)=n\left|X(t)+Y(t)=m\right.\right)$ is not well-defined in the first place, in general.