# Generator of sum of independent Markov processes

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process

The infinitesimal generator of a stochastic process is given by
$$
Af(x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\mathbb E_xf(X_t) - f(x)}{t},
$$
I want to find the generator for the sum and difference of independent Markov processes, $X_t \pm  Y_t$. I remember reading somewhere that the sum of the generators is the generator of the sum but can't seem to prove it. Is that correct? Can anyone please provide some reference for this?

Comment: Too bad it is in Spanish but if you are interested I can leave you a link where I think you can find your answer.
https://espanol.libretexts.org/Estadisticas/Teoria_de_Probabilidad/Probabilidad%2C_estad%C3%ADstica_matem%C3%A1tica_y_procesos_estoc%C3%A1sticos_(Siegrist)/16%3A_Procesos_de_Markov/16.01%3A_Introducci%C3%B3n_a_los_procesos_de_Markov

Comment: $X_t \pm Y_t$ is not necessarily a Markov process at all: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365430/when-the-sum-of-independent-markov-chains-is-a-markov-chain

Comment: If you sum the generators, you get (formally) the generator of a sort of "interlaced" process $Z_t$.  Run a process where you follow the transition function of $X_t$ for time $\epsilon$, then the transition function of $Y_t$ for time $\epsilon$, and repeat.  Then let $\epsilon \to 0$, and the resulting process is $Z_t$.  This is essentially the [Trotter product formula](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Trotter_product_formula).  But it is not anything like $X_t + Y_t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any references where this kind of result is proved?

Comment: Not offhand, sorry.  For finite-state continuous-time Markov chains, the proof basically *is* the Trotter product formula, plus the Markov property.  For more general state spaces, you have some domain issues when you add unbounded operators; so presumably some technical assumptions are needed, but I'm not sure what they are.